# How do I interpret this "Your question does not meet our quality standards" error?

Tags: support, asking-questions

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>   It does not meet our quality standards.

Thats the message I'm getting while trying to post a question. I've seen it a couple times before, usually solved by starting my sentence with a capital letter. Not this time.

My title is a true question. The title and body are in correct English. I have added a tag. I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

So my questions here are: What triggers this message? What are these standards?

and as a suggestion: for askers, adding a line to the above message explaining why it didn't meet the quality standards.

The question was:

Title:

> What does a compositor do?

Body:

> I know it's used for true transparancy. But what else is it good for?

Tag:

> compositing

Comment: can you quote the text here, so that we can check out what the system might be complaining about?

Comment: @Stefano Palazzo I've added my original attempt to the question.

Comment: Also, please [research](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Perhaps read a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositing_window_manager) page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is explained here:

- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/)

From checking out your questions you can probably do with adding some length to the question.