# What are the quality standards for posting questions here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I interpret this “Your question does not meet our quality standards” error?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1504/how-do-i-interpret-this-your-question-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards-erro)

I keep trying to post a question and it won't let me because

> It does not meet our quality standards.

I'm just leaving the tags from my original question because I don't know how to categorize this one.

Seriously all I want to know is if there's a program that will rip the songs from my iPod so I can save them to my computer.

Comment: as for the "it does not meet our quality standards" part see this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1504/how-do-i-interpret-this-your-question-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards-erro

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Comment: o thanks that helped